# How can I run a function after a user gets registered Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am developing a server using Django and wanted when a user registered to run a function that would create a directory with the username. The folder with the new user name will be saved in Collections. My code is as follows:

**Models.py**

```py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models 
    import (BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser)  

    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a user with the given variables and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password=None, is_admin=True):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given variables and password.
        """
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            is_admin = is_admin,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, unique=False)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, unique=False)
        user_collection = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='NotCreated', unique=False)

        objects = UserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username

        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return True

        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return True

        @property
        def is_staff(self):
            return self.is_admin
```

**Directory images**

[image]

Is there any way that I can accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model method on the `User` model and use python's `os` module to create the respective directories per user.

```py
import os
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    ...

    def add_to_collections(self):
        path = f'collections/{self.username}'
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)

    # overriden save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.add_to_collections()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, `add_to_collections` model method can be hooked into an overriden save or a post_save signal with a check if the model instance is created and saved for the first time.

Comment: Can you please help me with the signals?

Comment: @DeadSec you can refer to this blog post; There are really good examples of Django code snippets. I am sure he explains better than me.
 https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: Can he fiI just send a signal to create the file and save as normally?